# SQL CASE statement in simple query causing extreme slowness

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, performance

I've constructed a very simple query that's taking extremely long when using a CASE statement versus without. Could you please offer any insight?

Example 1: No CASE statement. Runs < 1s

```
select * from
(
    select  
        (row_number() over (order by b.BookName)) as RowNumber,
        b.*     
    from
        Books b (nolock) 
        inner join BookPublishRegions p (nolock)
          on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
    where       
        contains(p.PublishRegionName, 'France')
) as t1
where t1.RowNumber between 100 and 110
```

Example 2: Using CASE statement takes over 30 seconds

```
select * from
(
    select  
        case @SortBy    
            when 'Price' then
                (row_number() over (order by b.Price))
            else
                (row_number() over (order by b.BookName))           
        end as RowNumber,
        b.*     
    from
        Books b (nolock) 
        inner join BookPublishRegions p (nolock)
          on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
    where       
        contains(p.PublishRegionName, 'France')
) as t1
where t1.RowNumber between 100 and 110
```

I've actually run those queries as-is with the above hardcoded values. Parameter substitution for hardcoded values offers no benefit.

EDIT: Explicitly selecting the columns instead of b.* also offers no benefit.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One of the basic rules of writing efficient SQL is not to merge structurally different version of a query into a single one but rather keep them separate.

Comment: What if you run the query just sorting on `Price`?  That might be the performance issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: If I run just sorting on Price, or Price DESC, or BookName, etc. then it works fine. The problem occurs when I use that CASE statement to sort based on the SortBy parameter

Comment: Also... I suppose I could make separate procedures (variations of Example 1) for each column that I need to sort by.. But I was hoping there was a more efficient solution

Comment: Does adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this version?

```
select * from
(
    select row_number() over (order by b.Price) as rn_price,
           row_number() over (order by b.BookName) as rn_bookname,    
           b.*     
    from
        Books b (nolock) 
        inner join BookPublishRegions p (nolock)
          on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
    where       
        contains(p.PublishRegionName, 'France')
) as t1
where (t1.rn_price between 100 and 110 and @SortBy = 'Price') or
      (t1.rn_name between 100 and 110 and @SortBy <> 'Price')
```

I suspect this will also be slow.  In fact, you might have a situation where you just cannot speed up this query with options on the sort.  I am thinking that you have an index on `Books(BookName)` and `Books(Price)`.  These indexes get used for the `join` because SQL Server is smart enough to recognize that the index is useful for the `row_number()`, so returning the rows in order by the desired column is a good optimization.  The problem would then be that only one of these indexes could be used, so the `case` logic (or multiple row numbers) would prevent this optimization.

This is just a guess, but it might make optimizing your query rather difficult.

If this is the issue, then you can solve it by using dynamic SQL.  That would create the SQL for the specific option, and the optimizer would do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Unfortunately it's still taking about 33 seconds when I execute that query.

Comment: I'll try a dynamic SQL approach to see if this works. What would be the disadvantage of using it?

Comment: Also is there anything (in terms of best practices) wrong with creating different stored procedures for each column I want to sort by? I would imagine it would be a maintenance nightmare

Comment: @Ricky . . . Separate stored procedures are a maintenance nightmare if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sql Server 2012+` the use `OFFSET-FETCH` approach instead of `Row_number`. Try this.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   Books b (nolock)
       INNER JOIN BookPublishRegions p (nolock)
               ON b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
WHERE  CONTAINS(p.PublishRegionName, 'France')
ORDER  BY ( CASE
              WHEN @SortBy = 'Price' THEN Price
            END ),
          ( CASE
              WHEN @SortBy = 'Price' THEN NULL
              ELSE b.BookName
            END ) 
            OFFSET 99 ROWSFETCH NEXT 11 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: . . The solution is two expressions:  `order by (case when @SortBy = 'Price' then Price end), (case when @SortBy = 'Price' then NULL else b.BookName end)`.

Comment: Thanks @NoDisplayName however unfortunately I'm still on SQL 2008

Comment: @GordonLinoff - will keep this idea in mind thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this query but I think putting the case INSIDE the row_number function may solve your problem.

```
select * from
(
    select  
        (row_number() over (case @SortBy when 'Price' then b.Price else b.BookName end))           
        as RowNumber,
        b.*     
    from
        Books b (nolock) 
        inner join BookPublishRegions p (nolock)
          on b.BookKey = bp.BookKey
    where       
        contains(p.PublishRegionName, 'France')
) as t1
where t1.RowNumber between 100 and 110
```